# Should the Model class be a Singleton when using multiple Controllers?

Tags: ios

I am designing a To Do List iOS application. I have multiple table views, which all modify the same to do lists array. Should I use a singleton class for the to do list array model, so that it is always up to date, no matter which table view is accessing it?

Would it be better to have a single main controller class (singleton) which contains the model data as well, and has some methods to interact with the data. Then have the other controllers call these methods on the main controller?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the idea of MVC. You have one model, and multiple views of it, with interactions orchestrated by multiple view controllers.

You do not have to make your model a singleton, although this is a very common approach in iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

That would certainly be one way to do it, sure.

If you later decide you want to make your app document-based then you might need to go back and refactor, so think about future use first before you make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally viable to do so, but you lose the flexibility of potentially having multiple model objects. I'd personally suggest having a singleton "manager" of some sort, that gets the model from your backend (or wherever it's coming from), and holds a reference to the model.

Answer (score 0):

No, the model should not be a singleton. Singletons get overused. It's possible that you may wish to offer the user the ability to create more than one todo list. Maybe one for home and one for work, for example. Each list would be a separate instance of the todo list data model.

Using a singleton would prevent you from having more than one active todo list.